# I cannot change HTML with .innerHTML. keep getting message "cannot set innerHTML property of null"

Tags: javascript

My javascript to get the day and time and to place it in the div is as below:

```
function print(message){
  var div1= document.getElementById("date-and-time");
  div1.innerHTML= message ;
 }
function addZero(i) {
  if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i;}
  return i;
}

function todaysDate (){
  var today= new Date();
  var day= today.getDay();
  var daylist=["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday", 
  "Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
  var whatDayTime = "<p> Today is " + daylist[day] + ". </p>";
  var hour= addZero(today.getHours());
  var minute= addZero(today.getMinutes());
  var second= addZero(today.getSeconds());
  whatDayTime += "<p> The time is " + hour + ":" + minute+ ":" + second + ".
  </p>";
  return whatDayTime;
} 

print(todaysDate());
```

HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Practice JavaScript</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="date-and-time">
</div>

<script src="practice.js"></script>
</body>
```

I keep getting the error message" cannot set property of innerHTML to null". help? Many thanks. i am a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

`date-and-time` is class name not id. You should add id to element,use like this,

```
<body>
<div class="date-and-time" id="date-and-time">
</div>
```

or change your function, use `getElementsByClassName` method, [Look at this article.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

```
function print(message){
  var div1= document.getElementsByClassName("date-and-time");
  div1[0].innerHTML= message ;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

When looking for an element with an id, that element must exist. You used class instead of id.

False:

```
<div class="date-and-time"> </div>
```

Right:

```
<div id="date-and-time"> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. i'm a fool. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to **select element by class** instead of *id* using `querySelector`

Replace

```
var div1= document.getElementById("date-and-time");
```

by

```
var div1= document.querySelector(".date-and-time");
```

Answer (score 0):

> date-and-time is class name and you are accessing it by ID.

Either change attribute name to id or access element by class name or querySelector.